# azure: connect bot with LUIS

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have created a web app bot in **MS Azure** and a **LUIS Bot** on eu.luis.ai.
Now, I downloaded the bot from Azure, and filled in the appsettings.json. So far it worked and I could communicate with it using **BotFramework emulator**.

Now, I want to use my **LUIS Bot** instead, and as I understand it, I have to modify my .bot file for that. It contains 6 auto-generated Services: (I removed the ids, passwords and some other private information)

```
"services": [
    {
      "tenantId": "",
      "subscriptionId": "",
      "resourceGroup": "",
      "serviceName": "HenryEDP",
      "type": "abs",
      "name": "HenryEDP",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "connectionString": "",
      "tenantId": "",
      "subscriptionId": "",
      "resourceGroup": "",
      "serviceName": "henryedpbc32",
      "type": "blob",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "appId": "",
        "appPassword": "",
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
        "type": "endpoint",
        "name": "development",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "appId": "",
      "appPassword": "",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:3980/api/messages",
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "production",
      "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "instrumentationKey": "",
        "applicationId": "",
        "apiKeys": {},
        "tenantId": "",
        "subscriptionId": "",
        "resourceGroup": "",
        "serviceName": "HenryEDP2a7jx7",
        "type": "appInsights",
        "id": "5"
    },
    {
      "appId": "",
      "authoringKey": "",
      "version": "0.1",
      "region": "westeurope",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "BasicBotLuisApplication",
      "id": "6"
    }
  ]
```

Now I guess(can't find a decent documentation), I have to edit the last one. I replaced appID and appPassword with the information of my LUIS Bot, so that it looks similar to this (I changed some numbers for anonymity), the region was the same as my bot.

```
{
  "appId": "9845d1ff-5d83-41fe-f1d7-963c45e27b36",
  "authoringKey": "36360b0264589c24a0bc50a7f4fc7bb5",
  "version": "0.1",
  "region": "westeurope",
  "type": "luis",
  "name": "BasicBotLuisApplication",
  "id": "6"
}
```

Now when I try to run the bot, I get the Exception at

```
try
{
    botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath, secretKey);
}
catch
{
    var msg = @"Error reading bot file. Please ensure you have valid botFilePath and botFileSecret set for your environment.
- You can find the botFilePath and botFileSecret in the Azure App Service application settings.
- If you are running this bot locally, consider adding a appsettings.json file with botFilePath and botFileSecret.
- See https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot file its use and bot configuration.
";
    throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you encrypted your bot using the bot secret?? your bot secret value needs to be placed in the appsettings.json file. Place the encryption key there if the bot is encrypted or else ""

Comment: As @MandarDharmadhikari mentioned, if you .bot file uses a bot secret then the values in your bot file will be encrypted. Manually replacing values in the bot file may be bypassing the encryption resulting in an error. It's ok to copy encrypted values within the file. But, if you are adding values you need to edit the file in BotFramework Emulator or use the msbot CLI commands (https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/MSBot). Did this help?